# Get-PowerBIActivityEvent Unable To Parse Results

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I seem to be unable to parse the results of Get-PowerBIActivityEvent

Simple script.

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount 
$BIEventLog = Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime 2024-02-05T00:00:00 -EndDateTime 2024-02-05T23:59:59
foreach ($Event in $BIEventLog)
{
    Write-Host $Event.Id
}
```

But Id comes back as nothing / blanks. There are results, as I can run just the Get-PowerBIActivityEvent and see the data..

[image]

Usually, I can fumble my way through PowerShell but this one has me stumped.

Could someone give me a hint here PLEASE?

Comment: Your command is outputting a Json, try `Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime ..... | ConvertFrom-Json`

Answer (score 0):

As Santiago said, | -ConvertFrom-Json did the trick :)